# Why doesn't my stored procedure return anything on this windows form?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am trying to have my `DataGridView` populate when the stored procedure runs but it doesn't seem to update how it should. I am creating a windows form that has a grid with a button underneath to update or delete the record. The edited name is stored when it hits the breakpoint but is not showing up in the gridview when the popup is closed.

```
DataTable t = new DataTable
{
    Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
};

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[AAEmailAddressPersonUpdate]",connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", _firstName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", _lastName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", _emailAddress);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessEntityID", _businessEntityID);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    t.Load(reader);
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Is it a SELECT or an UPDATE?  Your code tells us it's trying to do both?

Comment: Is the grid using the DataTable as a DataSource?  That code isn't posted.

Comment: This would be the UPDATE. I am not sure how to pass the dgvData.DataSource = t from the form to the popup

Comment: What is the code for the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

The code tries to load a DataTable, which is already interesting given the verb in procedure name is "Update". Moreover, DataTable is only a memory construct. You need to bind it to the DataGridView control on the form before you will see anything.

Also, it's not clear what purpose `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` serves here. I'm sorry to say that kind of oversight makes us suspect you *really* don't know what you're doing, and maybe need to back up a few steps.

Answer (score 0):

`command.ExecuteReader();` will return any select statement in an `UPDATE` stored procedure.

So if you are returning any select statement after update - you will have reader.

If the stored procedure does not return anything -> use `ExecuteNonQuery()`